# Git merge deleted and modified files

Tags: git, github

Here's the scenario:

I've forked a large open-source project that is updated on a daily basis. There's a giant folder filled with different libraries and I only need a few, so when I forked it I deleted the libraries I knew I would never use to make my life easier. However, when I try to merge or rebase with the upstream source, I see tons of conflicts because the files I've deleted in my forked repo have been modified in the upstream. What's the best way to continue to keep updated with the upstream without having conflicts with the deleted files?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a fork you're publishing or just personal use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't delete them. Just exclude them from your build. The only thing they should be doing in that case is taking up a small amount of disk space.

That being said, if you truly don't need them, there shouldn't be an issue to deleting the updated versions as well.